# Why does my tomato plant have tightly shrivelled green leaves?

Tags: leaves, tomatoes, greenhouse

I have a Tomato Grafted Stargold F1 (Yellow Cherry) growing in my greenhouse.  It has been in there for several weeks and it seems to have grown taller but all the leaves are very tightly curled in.

[image: Image of shriveled F1 Tomato Plant]

What could have caused this tomato plant leaves to wither so, and get not discolour?

What could I do to improve the tomato plant's health?

---

The neighbouring tomato and pepper plant seems healthy.  The plants are in the greenhouse soil which is fresh garden soil and well-rotted horse manure.  I have not started feeing the tomatoes yet, as they do have any flower or fruit started yet.

I had not pruned any of the plants yet.  This morning I pinched out the extra shoots.  I would estimate it like the other tomato plants are twice the height they were.

Comment: I did have a little look around before posting this without finding a similar looking problem.  Then in the sidebar this question popped up: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/33847/what-is-the-cause-of-this-tomato-plant-leaf-curl?rq=1 Looks quite similar.  Perhaspe root damage and I should lift it out to check?

Comment: Was it different when you got it? Doesn't look like root damage. It *looks* more like a virus or herbicide drift. Maybe a genetic mutation.

Comment: Was the plant underwatered at one point, or did it get too hot?

Comment: @Shule I think it looked a little droopy when I got it, like the other two that now look fine did.  I am confident the leaves did not look this shrivelled.  As it has looked like this from the start, it could have been underwatered before I purchased it as a young plant.  It was from the same place as the other two tomatoes that seem to be OK.  I would assume it received similar care and watering.

Comment: An update on the plant.  It made it through the season, was perhaps a little smaller than the other plants in the greenhouse but it cropped well despite the strange leaf shapes.  I might try to grow some seeds from it to see if it repeats next year, but I do not know how tomatoes behave seed wise.  Another question!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like 2,4-D herbicide damage, but it could possibly be a virus (some viruses have similar symptoms). If you have lots of aphids, whiteflies, or such, I would suspect a virus.