# Anyone could give me a tip about what´s happening with my tomato plant

Tags: tomatoes

Hello (: i am a beginner in this matters, could anyone give me a hand by helping me find what´s wrong with my tomato plant. Principally the symptom, which i hope you can see by the picture, is that the new leaves are really wrinkled and weak. What you think it could be?

Thanks(:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Curled up, thick and leathery?  I have encountered this a couple times in the last few years on several plants.  I grow raised bed garden with about 6 plants and a few containers.  I am convinced it is drift from herbicide or herbicide in the grass clipping that I used as mulch.

I have learned through my experiences that tomato plants are very fragile to certain enemies and herbicide is one of them.  I don't think I got any droplets of herbicide on the plants, but studies have shown that even vapor from evaporating mist can damage them.  This year, I am going to cover the plants with sheets when I spray my lawn.

[What is the cause of this tomato plant leaf curl?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/33847/what-is-the-cause-of-this-tomato-plant-leaf-curl)

Comment: Hello Evil Elf. First of all thank you for your comment. Yeah I think it´s possible, but is strange because in my backyard I never apply any herbicide... you don´t think it´s possible to be because of the ribbons of tutoring being to much tie to the stem?? In the other day I notice that the strips were a little bit tie....

Comment: I don't know, the plant looks great but for that leaf curl.  Any neighbors spray for weeds?